# How to disable sending email from salesforce Org.

Tags: community, administration, configuration

I have a scenario where no email should not be sent to any user from salesforce.
If I disable send email through profile permission then the email will send either from chatter or through workflow.. How to disable even from workflow or chatter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Setup -> Email Administration - > Email Deliverability

Set to "No Access"

This will stop ALL email from being sent which seems like what you want. Be aware though it could cause code to throw errors if you have any code attempting to send email without checking availability first.

[image]